# Delete a blog post title with no content - octopress

Tags: git, command-line, blogs, octopress

Hi I'm learning Git for the first time and I'm working in Octopress.

For some reason, it created 2 blog posts that I don't want. The last 2. "Heller, I like cheese" and for some reason a blank one. These posts don't have content in them. I can't figure out how to delete them. I'm googled all over but the answers don't help.

Any idea?

Here's the link: http://danielleschechter.github.io/blog/archives/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the corresponding post in `source/_posts` and deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -f source/_posts/the-useless-post.md
rake generate
rake deploy
```

If you has commit it to git repository, remove it from repos first.